# EPS image distorted in overleaf

Tags: eps, overleaf

I use overleaf to write my thesis and I've produced an image using gnuplot that looks perfectly fine when I view it with an image editor, however when I import my image to overleaf and render it with `\includegraphics`, the text part of my title of the image is displaced a bit, the bottom text becomes blurred and the whole image itself becomes slightly distorted and it looks a big strange:

The original image included into overleaf
[image]

The image after compiled and viewed in the pdf
[image]

I use the `graphix` package and I read somewhere I should included `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in my preamble but it didn't do anything. I don't know why this is happening. At first I thought it might be a result of my plot with gnuplot but the text gets blurred and distorted after it's used in overleaf.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I specified a font in gnuplot (Arial) and then when I included the image file, there were no distortions.

Comment: my guess would be that the EPS file does not include the font it is using but just references it by name, so if you use it on a system without that font it tries to use a different font with the original metrics....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is strange because I did not specify the font on this image and a different image and the different image had no image defects or distortions. I tried specifying a font (Arial) and rendered it again in overleaf, there were no distortions this time. Thanks!

Comment: I am confident that David is correct, about the font. Search around the Internet for how to embed the font in the eps (or rather, in the pdf). Too detailed for a short answer, and the exact code depends on your circumstances. Short version: Put the font (may need to be Type 1) in the working directory. Use ghostscript, and use the -P flag so that it looks for a font in the working directory, not just in the usual ghostscript locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my guess would be that the EPS file does not include the font it is using but just references it by name, so if you use it on a system without that font it tries to use a different font with the original metrics...